# I don't want to update admob banner ads in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating voice collection app separated 4 genres(I control genres by using switch statement).You can choose one in four genres in segmentedcontroll and change buttons shown above segmentedcontroll. And I'm creating Buttons by using double for　statement.
When changing genres and updating Button I coded like

loadView()
viewDidLoad()

to update buttons.But that update banner ads(disappear and appear again)
as well.How can I  stop updating banner ads?.Sorry for my poor English and messy code.Thank you.

I used addsubView but which didn't work.

```
 //this is a part of whole code 

 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation
 import GoogleMobileAds

 class ViewController: UIViewController{

var spaceForiPhoneX = 0
var fontOfText = 9

var adView:UIWindow! = UIWindow()
var admobView:GADBannerView!

var window:UIWindow!

// true:テスト
let AdMobTest:Bool = true

var player = AVAudioPlayer()

var buttonArray:[UIButton]!



var currentArray:[String] = []

var first = true

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
    return true
}


lazy var  buttonSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {

    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["outou","outou2","bougen","meigen"])
    sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sc.tintColor = UIColor.white
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonsChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()


@objc func handlebuttonsChange(){


    switch  buttonSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:
        currentArray = outou
    case 1:
        currentArray = outou2
    case 2:
       currentArray = bougen
    case 3:
       currentArray =  meigen
    default:

        print("not selected")

    }

    loadView()

    viewDidLoad()


}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if(first) {

        currentArray = reloadViewController.outou


        first = false

        print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: \(GADRequest.sdkVersion())")

        var admobView = GADBannerView()

        admobView = GADBannerView(adSize:kGADAdSizeBanner)
        // iPhone X のポートレート決め打ちです
        admobView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:0, y:self.view.frame.size.height - admobView.frame.height + CGFloat(spaceForiPhoneX))
        admobView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height:admobView.frame.height)


        admobView.adUnitID = TEST_ID

        admobView.rootViewController = self
        admobView.load(GADRequest())

        navigationItem.titleView?.addSubview(admobView)


    }



    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 61, g: 91, b: 151)


    let numberOfrows = 6
    let numberOfLines = 3
    var count = 0
    var buttonArray:[UIButton] = []

    let sizeOfButton = view.frame.height / 10
    let widthOfSpace = ((view.frame.width - sizeOfButton * 4)  /  5 )       

    forloop : for row in 0 ... numberOfrows {

        for line in 0 ... numberOfLines {

            let button  =  UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 1, g: 101, b: 161)

            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
            button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            button.setTitle(currentArray[row * 4 + line], for: .normal)
            button.frame = CGRect(x: (widthOfSpace + sizeOfButton) * CGFloat(line) + widthOfSpace, y: view.frame.height / 9.3 * CGFloat(row) + 50, width: sizeOfButton ,height: sizeOfButton )
            button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            button.layer.borderWidth = 1
            button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontOfText))
            button.tag = row * 4 + line
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPushed), for:.touchUpInside)
            button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
            buttonArray.append(button)

            count += 1
            if (count == currentArray.count)  {break  forloop}

        }

    }

    for button in buttonArray{
        view.addSubview(button)
    }


    view.addSubview(buttonSegmentedControl)
    setupbuttonSegmentedControl()


}


@objc func buttonPushed(button : UIButton){

    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: currentArray[button.tag], ofType: "mp3")

    do {

        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))

        player.play()

    }catch{

        print(error)
    }
}

func setupbuttonSegmentedControl(){
    buttonSegmentedControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonSegmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -90).isActive = true
    buttonSegmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
    buttonSegmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem. Don't just dump whole classes into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call `loadView` and `viewDidLoad` by yourself. This is even mentioned in the documentation.

Extract the button update part from `viewDidLoad` to a separate method and call that method instead.

For example:

1. Declare an instance variable to store the buttons:

   ```
   private var buttons: [UIButton] = []
   ```
2. And extract the update code into a method:

   ```
   private func updateButtons() {
       for buttons in buttons {
           button.removeFromSuperview()
       }

       let numberOfrows = 6
       let numberOfLines = 3
       var count = 0
       buttons = []

       let sizeOfButton = view.frame.height / 10
       let widthOfSpace = ((view.frame.width - sizeOfButton * 4)  /  5 )       

       forloop : for row in 0 ... numberOfrows {

           for line in 0 ... numberOfLines {

               let button  =  UIButton(type: .custom)
               button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 1, g: 101, b: 161)

               button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
               button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
               button.setTitle(currentArray[row * 4 + line], for: .normal)
               button.frame = CGRect(x: (widthOfSpace + sizeOfButton) * CGFloat(line) + widthOfSpace, y: view.frame.height / 9.3 * CGFloat(row) + 50, width: sizeOfButton ,height: sizeOfButton )
               button.layer.cornerRadius = 10
               button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
               button.layer.borderWidth = 1
               button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: CGFloat(fontOfText))
               button.tag = row * 4 + line
               button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPushed), for:.touchUpInside)
               button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
               buttons.append(button)

               count += 1
               if (count == currentArray.count)  {break  forloop}
           }
       }

       for button in buttons {
           view.addSubview(button)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call this method from both `viewDidLoad` and from `handlebuttonsChange`.

By the way, note that the code could be significantly simplified and ideally you should use `UICollectionView` instead.

Comment: thank you for your answering.  What you mean important part  is a part creating buttons by using for statement?

Comment: I meant the whole "button update" part of `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I didn't know removeFromSuperview method so I thought I have to use viewdidload()  to update.I will check UICollectionView.

Comment: oh sorry . This is first time to post.Thank you again!